# ¿Como restaurar unos archivos de la SD al Databases?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

llevo ya algún tiempo atascado con esto y no le veo solución.
He conseguido realizar una copia de la base de datos de la carpeta Databases que está dentro de mi proyecto haciendo un respaldo en la SD, pero el problema es que no puedo restaurar estos archivos de la SD otra vez a la carpeta Databases.
Os agradecería cualquier ayuda. O cualquier código que me pudiese servir para este menester.

¿Por cierto si yo creo un archivo ".sqlite" porque se crean uno ".sqlite-wal" y otro ".sqlite-shm"?.
Espero vuestra ayuda y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si lo que deseas es volver a copiar en el almacenamiento interno debes tener permisos ROOT, de otra forma no es posible. Recuerda realizar tus preguntas en base a [ask].

Comment: Muchas gracias, entonces crearé las bases de datos directamente a la SD, porque si se desinstala la app por cualquier motivo se borraron todas las bases de datos creadas y no habría manera de respaldarlas, no todo el mundo es root.

Comment: También he visto que en la SD dentro de la carpeta Android se crea también un grupo de carpetas del proyecto en la que está la carpeta Files. Crearé ahí las bases de datos y en una carpeta externa los backups.